# Bad behavier of Openmp on calling a specified function

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

Dears, I'm having a issue with parallel paradigm (openmp). Perhaps it is a trivial problem. I'm trying to call the same function two times to initialize  two variables related to some struct.

If a try to initialize each variable without parallelism, the function works well an return each one correctly. But if I try to use the openmp, then the function don't works (it give the wrong answer).

See the code bellow.

Ps. The function only use the values to creat some structure, i.e., these values aren't change in any moment inside the function.

I tried use the "#omp parallel for", the standart "#omp parallel" and even "#omp parallel private(g, r, s)".

```
//this is on version
#pragma omp parallel for
  for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    if(i == 0)
      h[i] = fastContComplete(r, cromo->g, 1);
    else
      h[i] = fastContComplete(s, cromo->g, 0);
  }

//the second try
 #pragma omp parallel private(r, s, cromo)
  {
    i = omp_get_thread_num();
    if(i == 0)
      h[i] = fastContComplete(r, cromo->g, 1);
    else
      h[i] = fastContComplete(s, cromo->g, 0);
  }
```

Bellow I provide the algorithm of the function fastContComplete together with its dependences. To use it, you can creat a random struct grafo using the function criarGrafo(int n) and then one can test the function fasContComplete in the two different ways described above. Sorry, I couldn't make the algorithm shorter :(

```
void fastContAux(int k, int *cam, int K, int i,int *v,grafo *h, grafo *g, int clique){

  if(h == NULL || g == NULL){
    printf("Error... Grafos inacessíveis fastContAux!\n\n");
    exit(0);
  }
  if(v == NULL){
    printf("Error... vetor inacessível fastContAux!\n\n");
    exit(0);
  }

  if(k > 1){
    int m = i;
    int *v1;
    int key = 1;
    int l;

    while(m < g->size && key ==1){
      m++;
      if(v[m] == 0)
        key = 1;
      else
        key = 0;
    }
    if(m < g->size){

      v1 = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*g->size);

      while(m < g->size){
        if(v[m] == 1){
          for(int j = m+1; j < g->size; j++){
            if(v[j] == 1){
              if(edge(m, j, g) == clique)
                v1[j] = 1;
              else
                v1[j] = 0;
            }
            else{
              v1[j] = 0;
            }
          }
          cam[K-k] = m;
          fastContAux(k - 1, cam, K, m, v1, h, g, clique);
        }
        m++;
      }
      free(v1);
    }
  }
  if(k == 1){
    for(int j = i+1; j < g->size; j++){
      if(v[j] == 1){
        h->aux++;
        cam[K-k] = j;
        for(int t = 0; t < K; t++){
          for(int u = t+1; u < K; u++){
            setEdge(edge(cam[t], cam[u], h) + 1, cam[t], cam[u], h);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

grafo *fastContComplete(int k, grafo *g, int clique){
  int *v;
  grafo *h, *haux;
  int l;
  int *cam;

  if(k < 1){
    printf("Error... não existe grafo completo de tamanho nulo ou negativo! \n\n");
    exit(0);
  }

  h = criarGrafo(g->size);
  if(k == 1){
    h->aux = h->size;
    return h;
  }

  int nthreads = 4;
#pragma omp parallel private(v, cam, haux) shared(g, h, clique) num_threads(nthreads)
  {
    v = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*g->size);
    cam = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*k);
    haux = criarGrafo(g->size);
    for(int i = 0 + omp_get_thread_num(); i < g->size - k + 1; i += nthreads){
      cam[0] = i;
      for(int j = i+1; j < g->size; j++){
        if(edge(i, j, g) == clique)
          v[j] = 1;
        else
          v[j] = 0;
      }

      fastContAux(k-1, cam, k, i, v, haux, g, clique);
    }

#pragma omp critical (alimentando)
    {

      h->aux += haux->aux;
      for(int l1 = 0; l1 < h->size; l1++){
        for(int l2 = l1+1; l2 < h->size; l2++){
          setEdge(edge(l1, l2, haux)+edge(l1, l2, h), l1, l2, h);
        }
      }

    }

    free(cam);
    free(v);
  }
  return h;

}
void setEdge(float valor, int i, int j, grafo *g){
  if(g == NULL){
    printf("Aconteceu um erro de acesso na função setEdge.\n Grafo passado NULO\n\n");
    exit(0);
  }
  if(g->adj == NULL){
    printf("Aconteceu um erro de acesso na função setEdge.\n Grafo passado NULO não iniciado devidamente\n\n");
  }

  g->adj[formu(i, j, g->size) - 1] = valor;
}
float edge(int i, int j, grafo *g){
  if(g == NULL){
    printf("Aconteceu um erro de acesso na função edge.\n Grafo passado NULO\n\n");
    exit(0);
  }
  if(g->adj == NULL){
    printf("Aconteceu um erro de acesso na função edge.\n Grafo passado NULO não iniciado devidamente\n\n");
  }
  return g->adj[formu(i, j, g->size) - 1];
}
int formu(int i, int j, int n){
  int t;
  if(i < j){
    t = (2*n - i - 1)*i/2;
    return t + (j - i);
  }
  else{
    t = (2*n - j - 1)*j/2;
    return t + (i - j);
  }
}

typedef struct Grafo{

  int size;
  float *adj;
  int aux; //utilizada apenas em situaçoes de comparações                                                                 

} grafo;

grafo *gnp(int n){
  grafo *g;

  g = criarGrafo(n);

  for(int i = 0; i < g->size; i++){
    for(int j = i+1; j < g->size; j++){
      setEdge(((float) (rand()%2)), i, j, g);
    }
  }
  return g;
}

grafo *criarGrafo(int n){
  if(n > 1){
    grafo *g;
    g = (grafo *)malloc(sizeof(grafo));
    if(g == NULL){
      printf("Error ao alocar memória para criar um grafo\n\n\n");
      exit(0);
    }
    g->size = n;
    g->adj = (float *)malloc(n*(n-1)*sizeof(float *)/2);
    if(g->adj == NULL){
      printf("Error ao alocar memória para criar arestas de um grafo\n\n\n");
      exit(0);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
      for(int j = i+1; j < n; j++){
        setEdge(0, i, j, g);
      }
    }
    g->aux = 0;
    return g;
  }
  else{
    if(n == 1){
      grafo *g;
      g = (grafo *)malloc(sizeof(grafo));
      if(g == NULL){
        printf("Error ao alocar memória para criar um grafo\n\n\n");
        exit(0);
      }
      g->size = n;
      g->adj = NULL;
      g->aux = 0;
      return g;
    }

    printf("Error função Criar Grafo! Valor passado muito pequeno ou negativo (n = %d)\n\n",n);
    exit(0);
  }
}
```

Comment: You need a [mcve] that includes a complete, compilable and runnable program including the definition of this `fastContComplete()` function.

Comment: There's a point to creating minimal examples. Not only is it easier for others to spot the error, you may also spot the mistake yourself while creating the example. That said, you are running nested parallel for loops (did you enable this in openmp - this wouldn't cause a wrong value but simply cause the algorithm to run sequentially inside the first parallel region)? Furthermore, you modify the same `grafo` in both function calls, are you sure there are no race conditions there?

Comment: @Qubit Thanks for the help. I will try to create this MRE. About the others questions
i - (race) the fastConComplete() function only uses the variables g,k, clique for consultations. In any moment they change this values. So, i guess, that in this case the race condition isn't a problem. ii-> I always compile in gcc using the flag -fopenmp to be sure that the openm is enabled.

Comment: Enabling openmp with the compiler flag is not the same as making sure nested parallelism is enabled. As far as I know, that is disabled by default and must be enabled with the appropriate function calls.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that @Qubit. I going to search a little and try to see it.

Comment: The problem on second try is that `i` is shared. I don't know how to evaluate if your graphs are different from one version to another. It would be good if you provide a function where I can print some information to do it.
Also, you can use the `for` directive directly inside the `parallel` region without worry about dividing the iterations manually to each thread. I would recommend to you to test a `task` approach too.